# My CNN image classification model gives good predictions in all but 2 classes. What should I do?

Tags: cnn, image-classification

I built a CNN image classifier for a dataset that contains 6 classes. The dataset is balanced in all 6 classes. After training, the model gives pretty good prediction accuracy in all but 2 classes. To elaborate further, let us label these 6 classes with integers from '0' to '5'. The trained model does well in predicting classes from '0' to '3'. But almost 5%-10% of class '4' image is predicted as class '5' and similarly, 5%-10% of class '5' image is predicted as class '4'.

How should I deal with this situation?

Answer (score 1):

If these two classes are important to you **relative** to other classes, you should increase their  `class_weight` during training.

In Keras, for example, this would be a parameter in the `fit` function. Like

```
c_weights = {0: 1., 1: 1., 2: 1., 3: 1., 4:2., 5:2.}
model.fit(..., class_weight=c_weights)
```

In this case, most probably, you get better accuracy for your preferred classes and slightly worse accuracy for other classes. Is this what you are looking for?

Answer (score 1):

How well does a model trained to predict just classes 4 and 5 (trained and tested on the data for these two classes) perform? If that performs well, you could use this model as a second classifier. So initially classify the image using your original classifier; then if that predicts either class 4 or class 5, re-classify it using the second classifier.